# Downvotes after comments on a post

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

So like any other normal day, I was going through posts and found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3999457/734160) one. I found that the answer posted by the user DMcMor was lacking a proper explanation to the question. So I downvoted it and pointed out their mistake in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3999459/734160). After seeing their edited post(I dont understand why I couldnt see the edit history?), I was convinced that it answers the OP's question and immediately removed my downvote. Suddenly another user who has supposedly answered the same question accuses me of downvoting their answer. And then my heart felt heavy-there was a sudden drop of at least 50 reputation points from my account. I have attached the images of the same:

[image]
[image]

How can I seek out help?

Comment: You will be fine. Serial voting will be corrected automatically. But you can also flag one of your downvoted posts for moderator attention.

Comment: An extra click may be needed to see the vote summary on the timeline page.  Note the two part header.  By default the left block is highlighted, but clicking the "Show vote summary" block adds a (daily) summary of votes (currently 5 up, 4 down on that Answer).  Leaving Comments often leads users to suspect that the commentator is also the downvoter, and downvoting Answers is a cheap way to exact "revenge" however underserved.  Thanks for contributing to good content.

Comment: Oh God ! this is a real extreme of sereal downvoting! It has happened to me for three alternate days each time 6 serial downvotes , I changed my username and then i stopped getting those

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore downvotes is how you became the principle of hogwarts Lol

Comment: Some users downvote answers (even good answers) to poor questions, usually when there is no attempt in the question. I don't agree that much with this behavior, but anyway those questions often get deleted eventually, and upvotes and downvotes are deleted altogether.